# AS3 using an array in 2 different classes

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

for my school I have to create a small flash game.
I'm trying to create a sidescrolling flying game where you can also drop bombs.

The thing I'm not sure about is my bombs array I created this array in my plane class where the bomb movieclip is added to the array but I want to remove the bomb after it collided with an object in the bomb class but I'm not quite sure how to go about this the pushing of the bombs into the array goes fine. so this is what I have so far with regards to the array

for the variables:

```
public var bomb:MovieClip;
public var bombs:Array;
```

In the main function

```
        public function McPlane() {
        bombs = new Array();
```

In my update function

```
if(Input.bomb){
   if(bombs.length <=1){
        var bomb = new Bomb();
        stage.addChild(bomb);
        bomb.x = this.x + 30;
        bomb.y = this.y + 16;
        bombs.push(bomb);
```

so far this all works, 
my question is can I use the same array in my bomb class where I want to... pop the array when it collides with other objects? and if so how do I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the bomb from bombs in  plane class.Add an event listener for bomb when it created in plane class and the bomb will dispatch the target event when it collides.

```
var bomb = new Bomb();
stage.addChild(bomb);
bomb.addEventListener("bombCollides", onBombCollideHandler);

private function onBombCollideHandler(e:Event):void {

   var bomb:Bomb = e.target as Bomb;

   if (bomb) {

      var index:int = this.bombs.indexOf(bomb);

      //if find the target bomb, remove it
      if (index != -1) {
          bombs.splice(index, 1);
      }
   }
}
```

In Bomb class

```
public class Bomb {

   private function collide():void {

      //do some check if collide

      this.dispatchEvent("bombCollides");    

}
```